# "Your connection to matchmaking servers is not reliable" message on CS:GO?

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike-global-offensive

When ever I try and connect to a *Counter Strike: Global Offensive* (casual or comp) game it gives me this message:

> Your connection to matchmaking servers is not reliable.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you running your connection through a proxy?

Comment: It could be a proxy you're using, your ping cap, or even an unstable or weak connection itself.

Comment: Unless you're using a proxy/VPN (If so, give us some details), the answer is probably a simple "You need a better internet connection". Not very helpful I know, but with this information there's not much more to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

This message has appeared for me several times, and I followed the instructions on this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/3omuxf/your_connection_to_matchmaking_servers_is_not/) and it's worked for me every time.

1. Quit out of steam fully. Then run it as administrator. After launching steam, (assuming you're using Windows), open CMD and type in the following commands:
2. "ipconfig /release" - Will release your IP form your router (internet will not work for now)
3. "ipconfig /renew" - Will assign a new IP from your router (internet will work)
4. "ipconfig /flushdns" - Will flush DNS; helps with an overflow of packets.**

Try again, you should now be able to connect properly.